# Multicast to specific interface on macOS using Boost ASIO

Tags: c++, macos, boost, multicast, asio

I have a piece of code which sends out a multicast message on every ethernet network interface on a Mac (because the devices which respond could be on wifi or a wired ethernet connection). This code has been working fine for quite a while :

```
for(int i = 0; i < strIPAddresses.size(); i++)
{
   boost::asio::ip::address addr;
   addr.from_string(strIPAddresses[i]);
   m_pcDiscoverySocket->set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::outbound_interface(addr.to_v4()));
   m_pcDiscoverySocket->send_to(boost::asio::buffer((void*)pGetDeviceInfoMessage->m_pchData, pGetDeviceInfoMessage->m_ulDataSize), senderEndpoint);
}
```

Where strIPAddresses is a string array of the IP addresses of each network interface.

However, in macOS 10.12 something has changed in the way that this code is implemented and it seems to be ignoring the function setting the outbound interface and deciding for itself which the best interface to send the message. I can see this using Wireshark on another machine - it's seeing double of each message over wifi when the second message should be sent over the wired interface.

Does anyone know a way to force macOS to send a multicast message on a given interface, preferably using Boost ASIO?

Answer (score 0):

Binding a socket to an interface usually happens only *once* in a sockets lifetime. I could imagine that the case that a socket is re-bound to a different interface is just not working since it is untested, either in Boost or even in the OS.

What happens if you just try the wired interface, without first binding to the WiFi interface? If this works, you found a bug and you know the workaround.